# Stream movie on Apple TV 3 from iTunes on iMac G4

Tags: itunes, imac, appletv, streaming, movie

Is it possible to stream movies via old version of iTunes (iMac G4) on Apple TV 3 or is the latest version needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4437 says iTunes 10.2 or later is required.

If your iMac G4 can run OS X 10.5 (Leopard) you should be able to run iTunes 10.3.1 (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1103) which qualifies.

If it can only run OS X 10.4 it appears that the latest version is iTunes 9.2.1 (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4108495?start=0&tstart=0) which does not qualify.

Note that I have not verified the above.  Also, based on personal experience, you want as good a network connection between the source and the AppleTV as possible.  Either cabled or 11n wireless.

Good luck.

Comment: Right now I have Tiger installed but am planning to upgrade to Leopard. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Note that not all iMac G4's can run Leopard.

Comment: How can I tell that?

Comment: Check with Apple if your specific model is compatible with Leopard?

Comment: I have 1,25GHz iMac G4 and I can install it: http://support.apple.com/kb/SP517

Comment: As I've been streaming movies from iMac G4 for a while now I can confirm that it works perfectly. All movies can be streamed, also the ones in full HD res. That's really nice...